# Forward port w/o login access, socat, or ncat; unencrypted ok

Tags: mysql, port-forwarding

My intent is to have a local port that ultimately forwards to a mysql server on host `db.stuff.host.com`. However, `db.stuff.host.com` is only accessible via `login.host.com` (no root access), and I can't shell in to `db.stuff.host.com`. So `mysql -h db.stuff.host.com` works fine from `login.host.com`, but not my local Win7 computer (ssh is available via msysgit, cygwin, and a GUI program). How can I set things up so that if I run MySQL workbench, say, and point it to `localhost:30000`, it connects to `db.stuff.host.com:3306`?

Difficulty: socat and ncat are not and will not be installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is standard portforwarding if you are using ssh:

```
ssh -L30000:db.stuff.host.com:3306 user@login.host.com
```

This says "create a local port 30000 that passes through the ssh session to login.host.com and delivers any data on this port to db.stuff.host.com on port 3306".

Comment: \*groan\* \*punches self in face for being an idiot\*